# Import from index.ts returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this very simple file structure consisting of

- src

  - index.ts
  - services

    - my-service.ts

In index.ts I have the following

`export const a = 3`

and in my-service.ts I do,

```
import { a } from '../index'

console.log(a);
```

this logs `undefined`.

When I do

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(a), 100);
```

it logs 3.

I am running the solution using

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts
```

my tsconfig looks like

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  // "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "composite": true
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../shared-tools"
    }
  ],
  "exclude": ["dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Which extends the following root tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    // "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@project/shared-tools": [
        "../shared-tools/src"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`, and remove unrelated things from `my-service.ts` and `index.ts` until you have a [mre] and post the contents of those two now-minimal files. It sounds like you have a circular module dependency and you're having TypeScript convert your module syntax from JavaScript "ESM" syntax (which won't do what you have above) to Node's original CommonJS "CJS" syntax (which can do what you've shown above).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I posted the tsconfig

Comment: More about cycles in Node's CJS modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). (FWIW, I also explain in detail why this doesn't happen with JavaScript's ESM in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That symptom suggests you have a cycle of dependencies between `index.ts` and `my-services.ts` — in addition to the dependency you've described on `a` in `index.ts`, `index.ts` relies on something supplied (directly or indirectly) by `my-services.ts`. This is called a *cyclic dependency*. A depends on B which depends on A.

With JavaScript's now-standard ESM static module syntax, cycles are possible but normally they can be resolved without your having to worry about them. In cases where they can't, instead of getting `undefined`, you get an error (if you use `const` as you have).

But you're telling TypeScript to rewrite your module syntax into Node's original CommonJS-inspired syntax (`module.exports` and `require()` calls). With CJS, cycles can result in your seeing `undefined` for things that later have a value assigned when all the module code has been run.

Ideally, the solution is to remove the cyclic dependency. If `index.ts` has to depend on `my-services.ts`, perhaps move whatever `my-services.ts` imports from `index.ts` to something else they both import from. That way, A and B both depend on C rather than on each other.

If for some reason you can't do that, you might try telling TypeScript to output JavaScript module syntax instead (`"module": "ES2015"` or `"module": "ESNext"`). Since that does static resolution (if you don't use dynamic `import()`), it may be able to handle the cycles for you. Node now has [robust support for ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Or you may not need to handle it. Even in CJS, cyclic dependencies are really only a problem if you use the dependencies in the initial module code rather than in code that runs later in response to an event (as you saw by wrapping your code using `a` in a `setTimeout`). So if the resources involved in the cycles are only needed to (for instance) respond to a network request, you may not need to worry about it at all. There's a *bit* more about cycles in CJS modules in Node [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I appreciate your time.
With a different module type in compilerOptions, I am not able for some reason to use the path aliases correctly.

Comment: What I did now, is that I moved the variable `a` to another file, and I am importing in both index.ts and the service.ts files. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @AngularDebutant - Perfect. That's what I meant by the paragraph opening with *"Ideally, the solution is to remove the cyclic dependency..."*

Comment: This helped me fix my issue. Basically I was re-exporting all files inside a barrel/index file, but also importing some of them inside the files in the same directory the barrel file is. I switched the imports back to the way they were, without using a single one. Thanks man.